# Many to many on a single table in Rals

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

When we are dealing with two different database tables, Rails' ActiveRecord class allows us to setup a many-to-many association between them using `has_many :through` association. What if I want to create a many-to-many association on a single table? Does the ActiveRecord provide a special mechanism, or do we have to invent something else?

As an example, think of a table of soccer teams and as associations are games between each team.

For example, I can create the second table with two fields: `team1_id` and `team2_id` plus other additional fields if needed. But I would like to know whether or not there is a well-known widely accepted by Rails coders a technique to implement this association.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Self-joins**

There is a section in the [docs](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#self-joins) about self-joins:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :subordinates, class_name: "Employee",
                          foreign_key: "manager_id"

  belongs_to :manager, class_name: "Employee"
end
```

But in your (example) case, you don't want to use this technique, since it would lead to a model like:

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :opponents, class_name: "Team", foreign_key: "opponent_id"
  belongs_to :opponent, class_name: "Team"
end
```

which doesn't make much sense. A Team belonging to another Team? A Team can only have one opponent?

**Conclusion**

For your example it is better to use the `has_many :through` many-to-many association, so all teams can have unlimited opponents and you can store extra attributes in the relation like `match_date` or `final_score`.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was looking for. I don't believe how I could miss this section while I was looking through this document.